# Davening and Place

Tags: halacha, tefilla, makom-kavuah

I've seen people pacing back and forth during *davening*.

1. a) Is this a problem because of *makom kevuah*? 
   b) What the *halachic* parameters of having a *makom kevuah*?
2. Should one be in set place when he's *davening*?

Comment: I saw an article about this type of behavior once. How animals in backyard zoos feel confined and trapped which causes them to pace back and forth incessantly.

Comment: What does that have to do with what I'm asking?

Comment: Pacing = feeling trapped and a desire to get out. Not something you want to be feeling or displaying while standing before Hashem.

Comment: Can you try to find me this article and send me a link to it?

Comment: Here is an article that on discusses the [Halachos of Seats](http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol5Issue1.pdf).

Comment: This is not the article I read but a quick search came up with this https://www.thedodo.com/the-cute-zoo-animal-behaviors--601643824.html

Comment: I wasn't trying to be funny. When I read that article it really got me thinking about how I shouldn't walk around or look around or even in sfarim even during times when its 'allowed'. Kinda like when I saw in orchos yoshor that people who learn sfarim during times in davening when its not assur, are still showing they don't really believe Hashem is the room there with them.

Comment: When in Orchos Yoshor does it say that?

Comment: Where in [*Kuntres Hatefila*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43281&pgnum=1) does he say not to walk around during *davening*, and says that even if someone claims it helps them concentrate, they're wrong, it distracts them?

Comment: That he does not say and I didn't say he did. He says learnin in sefarim even at a time when its not assur still shows you don't believe Hashem is in the room. I thought I was clear about that. Sorry for the confusion.  As far as exactly where he says that, I will bli nedder check it up when I can.

Answer (score 2):

[The Rebbe Rashab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sholom_Dovber_Schneersohn) in Kuntres Hatefila says clearly not to walk around during davening, and says that even if someone claims it helps them concentrate, they're wrong, it distracts them. 
I don't have an answer to part 1 of your question. ( https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2155/6886)

Comment: Can you send me the link where he says this?

Comment: I can't find it online, but I'll take a photo of it when i have time